# PHP: Time difference (min:sec:tenths)

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, date-arithmetic

How can I calculate time difference when operating with `minutes:seconds.tenth` ?
For example how can I achieve this example: `40:24.5 - 67:52.4 = -27:27.9`

I was going to use this but then discovered lack of tenths:

```
$time1 = new date('40:24.5');
$time2 = new date('67:52.4');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%R%%i:%s:??');
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: @user574632: Not really... No.

Comment: Where have you found `date` class? And what kind of math is this `40:34.9 - 67:52.4 = +27:27.9` ?

Comment: discovered that I can't use date either as "H:i:s" is the closest I can get. My bad, it the math should show - not +.

Comment: Still, can you explain how did you calculate this `40:34.9 - 67:52.4 = -27:27.9` ?

Comment: it is from a result list, and I wrote down the wrong winner time as well :\ The correct should be '40:24.5 - 67:52.4 = -27:27.9'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you already "tried", you can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) extension:

```php
function time_difference($t1, $t2) {
    $t1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('i:s.u', $t1, new DateTimezone('UTC'));
    $t2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('i:s.u', $t2, new DateTimezone('UTC'));
    $diff = $t2->diff($t1);
    $u = $t2->format('u') - $t1->format('u');

    if ($u < 0) {
        $diff = $t2->modify('-1 second')->diff($t1);
        $u = 1000000 - abs($u);
    }

    $u = rtrim(sprintf('%06d', $u), '0') ?: '0';
    return $diff->format('%R%I:%S.') . $u;
}
```

Use example:

```php
echo time_difference('40:24.5', '67:52.4');
# -27:27.9
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/88034)</kbd>