# Find records between two time slots in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

i have time slots like

```
$timeslot = ['09:00-10:00', .... '23:00-00:00', '00:00-01:00'];
```

I have records with updated time as `23:15:00`, `23:30:00`, `00:15:00`, `09:15:00` etc.

What i'm trying to find is the sum of records between each of the `$timeslot`. I'm not considering what day got updated, only time i'm looking for.

i tried with:-

```
$data = ['23:15:00', '23:30:00', '00:15:00', '09:15:00'];
foreach($data as $val) {
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach($timeslot as $slots) {
        $slot = explode("-", $slots);
        if( (strtotime($val) > strtotime($slot[0])) && (strtotime($val) <= strtotime($slot[1])) ) {
            $up_time[$slot[0] . '-' . $slot[1]] = $cnt++;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($up_time);echo '</pre>';
```

The expected output is:-

```
09:00-10:00 = 1
23:00-00:00 = 2
00:00-01:00 = 1
```

Comment: I think we will need to know what `$data` is if you are going to get any useful help here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Time difference (min:sec:tenths)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044088/php-time-difference-minsectenths)

Comment: You will also need to change the output line to `echo '<pre>';print_r($up_time,true);echo '</pre>';` to see the output of the `print_r()` between the 2 Pre's

Comment: @executable nope.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Iwork on codeigniter framework which takes care all these things.

Comment: In order to see if `23:15:00` (`$data`) is in between `23:00-00:00` (`$slot`) you are going to have to split the `$slot` up into its 2 parts before attempring a comparison

Comment: So why are we trying to debug PSEUDO code, thats a great way to waste everybodies time you know

Comment: You cannot use a single `$cnt` either! The count is dependant on the range and not the number of times round the loop

Comment: And why is there a _static_ `strtotime('23:15:00')` in there? Surely that should be `strtotime($val)` then at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strtotime is not required since your time can be compared as strings.

This code works as you expected.

```
$data = ['23:15:00', '23:30:00', '00:15:00', '09:15:00'];
$timeslot = ['09:00-10:00', '23:00-00:00', '00:00-01:00'];
$up_time = array();
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $myTime = substr($val, 0, 5);
    foreach ($timeslot as $slot) {
        $times = explode("-", $slot);
        if (substr($times[1], 0, 3) == "00:") {
            $times[1] = "24:" . substr($times[1], 3);
        }
        if ($myTime >= $times[0] && $myTime <= $times[1]) {
            if (!isset($up_time[$slot])) {
                $up_time[$slot] = 1;
            } else {
                $up_time[$slot]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($up_time);
echo '</pre>';
```

The if with 'substr' is needed because for midnight you have '00' and not '24' so the computer thinks is an empty set (such as hours bigger then 23 and smaller then 0).

Comparison is made between string because bigger time is also a bigger string since you use 2 digits for hours.

You need to count equal slots so you need an array with an element for each slot and increment if duplicate or create an element if not found (the condition '!isset').

**Update for modification request**

```
$data = ['23:15:00', '23:30:00', '00:15:00', '09:15:00'];
// added unused slot 8:00-9:00
$timeslot = ['08:00-09:00','09:00-10:00', '23:00-00:00', '00:00-01:00'];
$up_time = array();
// new initialization
foreach ($timeslot as $slot) {
    $up_time[$slot] = 0;
}

foreach ($data as $val) {
    $myTime = substr($val, 0, 5);
    foreach ($timeslot as $slot) {
        $times = explode("-", $slot);
        if (substr($times[1], 0, 3) == "00:") {
            $times[1] = "24:" . substr($times[1], 3);
        }
        if ($myTime >= $times[0] && $myTime <= $times[1]) {
            $up_time[$slot]++;    // simplified
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we include time slots which doesn't have records. for example 09:00-10:00 = 0

Comment: I updated the answer adding a new unused slot 08:00-09:00.